# Error in Ajax call when using UUID

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, uuid

On a link click I invoke a method that makes an Ajax call. The problem is that When I use UUID string in the first parameter it throws an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`

Here's an example of the link:

```
onclick="fetchQuestion(ff8080814e6c440b014e6c464f660001,2);return false"
```

But When I use simple ID in the first parameter it works fine. Example :

```
onclick="fetchQuestion(3,2);return false"
```

Here is the fetchQuestion method implementation:

```
function fetchQuestion(questionId, index){
    $.ajax({
        url: '${createLink(action: 'fetchQuestion')}',
        data: {
            testAttemptedId: ${testAttemptedId},
            index: index,
            id: questionId,
            grantAssessmentId: ${grantAssessmentId}
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            $('div[id="questionContent"]').html(html);
        }
    });
}
```

Why it doesn't work in case of UUID ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As UUID is `string`, you need to wrap UUID in quotes.

```
onclick="fetchQuestion('ff8080814e6c440b014e6c464f660001', 2);return false"
//                     ^                                ^
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the value in quotes for it to be recognised as a string.

```
onclick="fetchQuestion('ff8080814e6c440b014e6c464f660001',2);return false"
```

Note that you should use Javascript to attach your events as it allows for a better separation of concerns. Try this:

```
<a href="#" data-uuid="ff8080814e6c440b014e6c464f660001" daat-index="2">Foo</a>
```

Then you can hook to that in JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        fetchQuestion($(this).data('uuid'), $(this).data('index'));
    });
});
```